# Xamarin shell initializing API Controller

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.shell

I have a running XF App with a lot of database accesses through an Azure API. So far all was running quite well.
Due to layout changes I changed to a shell based navigation. I worked through the whole stuff but faces a huge problem.
My app.xaml.cs is loding a lot of controllers:

```
Public partical class App : Xamarin.Forms.Application, INotifyPropertyChanged {public static CampaignController CampaignController { get; private set; }}
```

And in OnStart()

```
CampaignController = new CampaignController(new RestService());
```

In public App() I load the AppShell() as Mainpage

```
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

This is my AppShell.xaml

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EY365OCMobileApp"
         x:Class="EY365OCMobileApp.AppShell">
<ShellContent Route="WelcomePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:WelcomePage}">
    
</ShellContent>
```

The WelcomePage.xaml.cs looks like this:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            Campaigns = await App.CampaignController.GetCampaignsAsync(364840001);
            CarouselView.ItemsSource = Campaigns;
            BindingContext = Campaigns;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await CreateNewBug.CreateANewBug(ex.Message,"Error in Module " + ex.Source,"\nMessage---\n{ 0}" + ex.Message + "\nInnerException---\n{ 0}" + ex.InnerException + "\nStackTrace---\n{ 0}" + ex.StackTrace + "\nTargetSite---\n{ 0}" + ex.TargetSite);
            ToastOptions toastOptions = Message.ShowMessage("An error was raised and a new bug created in our system.", "error");
            await this.DisplayToastAsync(toastOptions);
        }
    }
```

This line creates an error:

```
            Campaigns = await App.CampaignController.GetCampaignsAsync(364840001);
```

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

When I debug it seems that the initialization of the app.xaml.cs doesn't run though because it jumps to the AppShell.xaml.cs. When I move the code from App.xaml.cs to AppShell.xaml.cs it brings the same error.
Any idea how to initialize the rest-service controller in a shell environment of Xamarin?

Comment: you could either instaniate `CampaignController` in the App constructor (if it's fairly lightweight) or you could lazy load it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lazy load the controller whenever you use it .

**App**

```
CampaignController _controller;
Public CampaignController controller{ 
   get
   {      
      if(_controller == null) 
      {
          _controller = new CampaignController(new RestService());
      }
      return _controller;  
   }
 }
```

**WelcomePage**

```
Campaigns = await (App.Current as App).controller.GetCampaignsAsync(364840001);
CarouselView.ItemsSource = Campaigns;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved the problem. I think I need to dig a little deeper into the shell stuff. I added you code for the App.xaml.cs into the public App() and changed the WelcomePage. Now it runs. Thanks a lot!